# What is the field inside the struct ext4_inode responsible for providing pointers to where data is actually located on disk?

Tags: kernel, filesystem, ext4, inode

I've been reading the ext4 documentation on kernel.org and in the struct ext4_inode section it is show a field named i_block. It says "Block map or extent tree". Does this field contain pointers or something like that to locate the actual data on disk ?